# File not found in php

Tags: php, html

I have been learning php. I have an issue the file is located in directory but it is not exacting. The browser gives me an error "file not found". The screen shots are attached bellow.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please use your ip address and then folder name. You have used wrong path. Please use path as this. `i.e 45.77.34/148/getyougo`

Comment: What file isn't found? What code you're using?

Comment: I have tried this but did not worked for me.

Comment: put a sample code of what you have done so far

Comment: connection.php not found

Comment: What is the root of your web-server?

Comment: You have to get the right path, use `../` to go a directory down, use `./` to start from current directory etc. you can find a list of them on the internet. You can also use a direct link like `www.mywebpage.com/connection.php`

Comment: thanks  Darshan Jain its working.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this url Into your browser

```
https://45.77.34.148/getyougo/connection.php
```

it will work...!!

Enjoy Happy Coding